# PHP Upload Data

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, upload

I am currently making a website where you can upload and download files like a cloud server or something of that sort. I was just wondering what happens if i dont have space on a Hard drive how would i tell PHP to upload to upload to a different hard drive and just stuff like that?

i have this code and i will be adding security but right now im testing:

```
<?php
set_time_limit(30000);
session_start();
include('../Connect/Connect.php');

$User = $_SESSION['User'];
$Get = 'SELECT * FROM Users WHERE Username = "'.$User.'"';
$Files = $_FILES['File'];
if(isset($User))
{
    if(!empty($Files))
    {
        if($Result = $Connect->query($Get))
        {
            while($Row = $Result->fetch_assoc())
            {
                $Limit = $Row['Limit'];

                for($X = 0; $X < count($Files['name']); $X++)
                {
                    $Name = $Files['name'][$X];
                    $TMP = $Files['tmp_name'][$X];

                    move_uploaded_file($TMP, '../Users/' . $User . '/' . $Name);
                }   
            }
        }
    }
}
else
{
    header("location:../"); 
}
header("location:index.php");
$Connect->close();
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could always use [disk_free_space()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.disk-free-space.php) before you try to upload/move files. Also, move_uploaded_file will probably return false, but that can be also because of other issues such as permissions.